# Decoding a 2-byte UTF-8 character: trouble arranging the bits

Tags: c, unicode, utf-8

I'm attempting to write a UTF-8 decoder in plain C, however right now I'm stuck on decoding characters encoded in the 2-byte form.

### Problem

Imagine I'm trying to decode the `Ƅ` (Codepoint **U+0184**, dec: 388) character. In memory it's represented as the bytes `0xC6 0x84`. By taking a look at its first byte I can see that it does in fact occupy 2 bytes in memory (because the first byte is in the form: `0b110xxxxx`).

Looking at the table, in order to obtain the character's codepoint from the two bytes, I need to extract the last 5 bits from the first byte, and the last 6 bits from the second byte (all represented by `x`s), and then 'combine' them to form a number.

[image: wikipedia utf-8 encoding sequences]

I've written macros for extracting the bits, but I have no idea how to combine them:

```
#define extract_2byte(b)  ((b) & 0x1F) // extract bytes from the form:              110xxxxx
#define extract_beyond(b) ((b) & 0x3F) // extract the bits of the byte in the form: 10xxxxxx
```

**I can easily extract the appropriate bits from the first and second byte, but I'm stuck on figuring out how to combine them.**

If I'm not mistaken, the final bit representation should look like this:

```
0b00000|00110|000100
  ^      ^      ^
  |      |      |
  |      |      last 6 bits of second byte
  |      |
  |      | 
  |      last 5 bits of first byte
  |
  | 
  padding bits to form a 2-byte value (0x184, 388)
```

Comment: `(extract_2byte(b1) << 6) | extract_beyond(b2)`

Comment: @Dmitri Thanks. I never would've figured that out on my own. In fact I was confused for a while after you posted this since my `uint8_t`s were getting properly shifted by 6 places despite, well, having only 8 bits, before I read that integer promotion is always performed on operands of the binary shift operators.

Comment: You could also do multiplication (which good compilers will transform to shift). in C all operation are done as if you did them with integer (or larger numbers). Again: you may add a cast (and good ocmpiler will understand and optimize). Note: Unicode wants that you do some tests on data. With your method (raw), you may extract `\0` (or other ASCII characters), which may bypass some security check

Comment: I know, I already test for 1-byte ASCII codepoints, this was just regarding the 2-byte form.